# How to create Categories/SubClass UILabel to change Label Color or Text Style

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, categories

i want to create Categories in Objective-C which will be the SubClass of UILabel , so with the help i can change the Label Color for all UILabel in application . please suggest some thing.

Comment: Hi Ankur, welcome to Stack Overflow.  You should read [ask] and try to write some code yourself.  Questions that don't attempt to provide an [mcve] usually get closed as off topic.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need categories to achieve this styling.

**1. Basic approach**

To change text color of all `UILabel` class instances in the whole application, use **appearance**

```
[[UILabel appearance] setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

**2. Worse approach**

In case you want to **subclass** `UILabel`, you would need to override its drawing methods. This is bad approach though.

**3. The worst approach**

If you insist to use **categories**, you can create category `UILabel+CustomColor` and implement method inside

```
+ (UILabel *)coloredLabel {
    UILabel *label = [UILabel new];
    label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

    return label;
}
```

The creation of this specific label would be:

```
UILabel *label = [UILabel coloredLabel];
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple says:

"The base UILabel class provides support for both simple and complex styling of the label text. You can also control over aspects of appearance, such as whether the label uses a shadow or draws with a highlight. If needed, you can customize the appearance of your text further by subclassing".

Check this two link : 
1. [How to Subclass UI elements like UILabel, UIButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686275/how-to-subclass-ui-elements-like-uilabel-uibutton). 
2. [SubClassing UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004466/subclassing-uilabel)

Comment: Also look at this accepted answer. You will get idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190927/uilabel-subclass

Answer (score 0):

You can set label Colour like this.

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
[label setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

If you want to set different text style then user NSAttributedString string and set this to label, Please refer following code snippet

```
NSString *textString;//Your text 
dict = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor],
                     NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor clearColor],
                     NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10],
                     NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @1
                     };
NSAttributedString *attributtedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textString attributes:dict];
[label setAttributedText:attributtedString];
```